# Replace of forward slash to backslash in ruby from any path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

After a lot of research and brainstorm finally i give up for it and need a help to convert the forwardslash to single backslash But I am not able to do.

Here is some steps which i followed but it does n't works

```
"C:/projects/test/code".gsub('/','\\')  => "C:\\projects\\test\\code" 

"C:/projects/test/code".gsub('/','\\\\') => "C:\\projects\\test\\code" 

"C:/projects/test/code".gsub('/',"\'\\'")  => "C:'projects/test/codeprojects'test/codetest'codecode"
```

The result which i expect to be should like:

```
=> "C:\projects\test\code"
```

Any help and suggestions accepted please help

Comment: Your question is unclear. "it does n't works" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @JörgWMittag let me update it for you

Comment: The first two snippets you posted show that your code works, so I'm not even sure what the problem is. And the expected result is not legal Ruby code, so I'm not sure what it is that you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

You did it already with this:

```
"C:/projects/test/code".gsub('\', '\\') # => "C:\\projects\\test\\code"
```

Likely you are confused by \\ in output. It's normal. Just try to puts this:

```
puts "C:/projects/test/code".gsub(/\//, '\\') # => C:\projects\test\code
```

**Updated:**

\ is used in Ruby (and not only) for multiline string concatenation so when you just type it in irb, for example, it continues reading user's input.

Some notes about irb:

when you execute some command in irb it outputs the result for debugging purposes:

```
irb> "foo\r\nbar"
=> "foo\r\nba"
```

This line contains \r\n what means go to the beginning of the new new line. So if you want to see it in human mode just print it and it gives:

```
irb> puts "foo\r\nbar"
foo
bar
```

If you want to prevent output you can use semicolon:

```
irb> s = "foo\r\nbar";
irb* puts s
foo
bar
```

Comment: why we need puts over can you explain if i normally execute it,it does not work. it's work with puts only why? @user3309314

Comment: "#{"C:/projects/test/code".gsub(/\//, '\\')}" how i interpolate with single

Comment: `puts "#{%(C:/projects/test/code).gsub(/\//, "\\")}"`

Comment: system "ln -s  #{%(C:/projects/test/code).gsub(/\//, "\\")}" something like that

Answer (score 3):

What you get in your first example is exactly what you need. In IRB/Pry the representation differs, because REPL is intended to support copy-paste, and the string you see is the exact string *with single backward slashes*, how one would type it inside double quotes. You might also note double quotes around the string in the REPL representation, which *do not belong to the string itself either*.

Here is another more explicit way to accomplish a task:

```
result = "C:/projects/test/code".split('/').join('\\')
#⇒ "C:\\projects\\test\\code"
```

See:

```
puts result
#⇒ C:\projects\test\code
result.count("\\")
#⇒ 3
```

---

As a matter of fact, Windows *does indeed understand* the path with forward slashes, so you probably don’t need this conversion at all.